# finding the frequency distribution of values in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have df (8360 x 3 columns)

```
            Time             A         B
0   01.01.2018 00:00:00   0.019098  32.437083
1   01.01.2018 01:00:00   0.018871  32.462083
2   01.01.2018 02:00:00   0.018643  32.487083
3   01.01.2018 03:00:00   0.018416  32.512083
4   01.01.2018 04:00:00   0.018189  32.537083
5   01.01.2018 05:00:00   0.017961  32.562083
6   01.01.2018 06:00:00   0.017734  33.189708
7   01.01.2018 07:00:00   0.017507  34.122968
8   01.01.2018 08:00:00   0.017279  32.897831
9   01.01.2018 09:00:00   0.017052  32.482338
```

and want to group the df after the numeric value of column B. I want to find out at what range the numbers in the column are increasing/decreasing the most (frequency distribution).
Right now I just use  `df.describe()` and play with the numbers.
for example I found out that they are 300 values which are smaller than 1
`new_df = df[df['B'] < 1]`

Is there a specific function to help me with this task?

Comment: Please share some example information so we can see what kind of data are you dealing with to help you achieve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get idea about distribution of values just plot histogram. For example in Jupyter notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
df.B.hist()
```

or compute cumulative frequency histogram with scipy

```
import scipy.stats
scipy.stats.cumfreq(df.B)
```